# How to extend LVM PV to the beginning of disk?

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

I have server with 2TB disk, that someone initially partitioned like this:

- 300GB standard primary partition for operating system files(CentOS 7).
- 1.7TB LVM with some pretty big logical volumes - for other needs.

Since actual size of of operating system files turned out to be just around 400GB, later it's been moved to it's own logical volume on LVM, so this 300GB partition at beginning of disk become unused.

So, I removed this partition, and now want somehow to move start position of PV to beginning of disk, so it will utilize whole disk space. But i can't find any tools to do so - `pvextend` can only extend PV to end of disk, not to beginning.

Yes I know that I can just add that old partition to VG as another PV, but having multiple PV's on single disk look's like something pretty weird.

Also I know that I can copy partitions to some external device or cloud storage, and then just recreate physical disk partitioning from scratch. But I don't want this because of long server downtime.

So, is there any way to just quickly extend PV to beginning of disk?

Answer (score 10):

### If your existing PV has < 300GB of data

If your existing PV has less than 300GB of data on it, then you can simply relocate that data to the front of the disk and then use `pvresize`.  First, create a new pv:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda1
```

Relocate data from the existing pv onto the new pv:

```
pvmove /dev/sda2 /dev/sda1
```

Remove the old pv:

```
vgreduce myvg /dev/sda2
```

Now, use `parted` or `fdisk` or whatever to resize `/dev/sda1` to cover the entire disk, and then use `pvresize` to extend the pv to cover the partition.

### Using an external device without downtime

You can use `pvmove` to relocate your data to a different device *without* any server downtime.  You would create a new pv:

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

Add it to your vg:

```
vgextend myvg /dev/sdb
```

Relocate data from your existing pv to the new pv:

```
pvmove /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb
```

Remove your existing pv from the volume:

```
pvremove /dev/myvg /dev/sda2
```

Now, repartition /dev/sda, create a new pv, and reverse the above process.

Comment: If you can't move the pv for some reason, you can also just create a second pv in the free space. You have to be careful when defining stripes then, because a stripe with two pv on the same disk would decrease performance.